# Code Your Own Cryptocurrency & ICO on Ethereum | Tutorial

Tags: solidity, blockchain

getting the following error

```
    Contract: DappToken
    ✔ initializes the contract with the correct values (106ms)
    1) allocates the initial supply upon deployment
    > No events were emitted
    2) transfers token ownership
    > No events were emitted
    ✔ approves tokens for delegated transfer (352ms)
    3) handles delegated token transfers
    > No events were emitted

  Contract: DappTokenSale
    4) initializes the contract with the correct values
    > No events were emitted
    5) facilitates token buying
    > No events were emitted
    6) ends token sale
    > No events were emitted


  2 passing (2s)
  6 failing

  1) Contract: DappToken
       allocates the initial supply upon deployment:

      sets the total supply to 1,000,000
      + expected - actual

      -0
      +1000000

      at /mnt/d/Practice/LEarn/BlockChain/Dapp/Cryptocurrency on Ethereum/token_sale/test/DappToken.js:26:14
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

  2) Contract: DappToken
       transfers token ownership:
     AssertionError: error message must contain revert
      at /mnt/d/Practice/LEarn/BlockChain/Dapp/Cryptocurrency on Ethereum/token_sale/test/DappToken.js:39:7
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

  3) Contract: DappToken
       handles delegated token transfers:
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at /mnt/d/Practice/LEarn/BlockChain/Dapp/Cryptocurrency on Ethereum/token_sale/test/DappToken.js:98:41

  4) Contract: DappTokenSale
       initializes the contract with the correct values:
     AssertionError: has token contract address: expected '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' to not equal 0
      at /mnt/d/Practice/LEarn/BlockChain/Dapp/Cryptocurrency on Ethereum/token_sale/test/DappTokenSale.js:21:14
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

  5) Contract: DappTokenSale
       facilitates token buying:
     AssertionError: cannot purchase more tokens than available
      at /mnt/d/Practice/LEarn/BlockChain/Dapp/Cryptocurrency on Ethereum/token_sale/test/DappTokenSale.js:61:7
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

  6) Contract: DappTokenSale
       ends token sale:
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at /mnt/d/Practice/LEarn/BlockChain/Dapp/Cryptocurrency on Ethereum/token_sale/test/DappTokenSale.js:78:32
```

following are the contract and test file

```
contract DappTokenSale {
    address payable admin;
    DappToken public tokenContract;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

    event Sell(address _buyAr, uint256 _amount);

    function DapptokenSale(DappToken _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
        admin = msg.sender;
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }

    function multiply(uint x, uint y) internal pure returns (uint z) {
        require(y == 0 || (z = x * y) / y == x);
    }

    function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {
        require(msg.value == multiply(_numberOfTokens, tokenPrice));
        require(tokenContract.balanceOf(address(this)) >= _numberOfTokens);
        require(tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens));

        tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;

        emit Sell(msg.sender, _numberOfTokens);
    }

    function endSale() public {
        require(msg.sender == admin);
        require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf(address(0x20f8dfdD8fCE9aB58d94c1b8c9e7EDFb9b1650D9))));

        // UPDATE: Let's not destroy the contract here
        // Just transfer the balance to the admin
        admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

contract DappToken

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract DappToken {
    string  public name = "DApp Token";
    string  public symbol = "DAPP";
    string  public standard = "DApp Token v1.0";
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    event Transfer(
        address payable indexed _from,
        address payable indexed _to,
        uint256 _value
    );

    event Approval(
        address indexed _owner,
        address indexed _spender,
        uint256 _value
    );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    function Dapptoken (uint256 _initialSupply) public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address payable _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;

        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address payable _from, address payable _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);

        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;

        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

javascript test file

```
var DappToken = artifacts.require("./DappToken.sol");

contract('DappToken', function(accounts) {
  var tokenInstance;

  it('initializes the contract with the correct values', function() {
    return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      tokenInstance = instance;
      return tokenInstance.name();
    }).then(function(name) {
      assert.equal(name, 'DApp Token', 'has the correct name');
      return tokenInstance.symbol();
    }).then(function(symbol) {
      assert.equal(symbol, 'DAPP', 'has the correct symbol');
      return tokenInstance.standard();
    }).then(function(standard) {
      assert.equal(standard, 'DApp Token v1.0', 'has the correct standard');
    });
  })

  it('allocates the initial supply upon deployment', function() {
    return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      tokenInstance = instance;
      return tokenInstance.totalSupply();
    }).then(function(totalSupply) {
      assert.equal(totalSupply.toNumber(), 1000000, 'sets the total supply to 1,000,000');
      return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
    }).then(function(adminBalance) {
      assert.equal(adminBalance.toNumber(), 1000000, 'it allocates the initial supply to the admin account');
    });
  });

  it('transfers token ownership', function() {
    return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      tokenInstance = instance;
      // Test `require` statement first by transferring something larger than the sender's balance
      return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 99999999999999999999999);
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
      assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'error message must contain revert');
      return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 250000, { from: accounts[0] });
    }).then(function(success) {
      assert.equal(success, true, 'it returns true');
      return tokenInstance.transfer(accounts[1], 250000, { from: accounts[0] });
    }).then(function(receipt) {
      assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, 'triggers one event');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event, 'Transfer', 'should be the "Transfer" event');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._from, accounts[0], 'logs the account the tokens are transferred from');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._to, accounts[1], 'logs the account the tokens are transferred to');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._value, 250000, 'logs the transfer amount');
      return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[1]);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 250000, 'adds the amount to the receiving account');
      return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 750000, 'deducts the amount from the sending account');
    });
  });

  it('approves tokens for delegated transfer', function() {
    return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      tokenInstance = instance;
      return tokenInstance.approve.call(accounts[1], 100);
    }).then(function(success) {
      assert.equal(success, true, 'it returns true');
      return tokenInstance.approve(accounts[1], 100, { from: accounts[0] });
    }).then(function(receipt) {
      assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, 'triggers one event');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event, 'Approval', 'should be the "Approval" event');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._owner, accounts[0], 'logs the account the tokens are authorized by');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._spender, accounts[1], 'logs the account the tokens are authorized to');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._value, 100, 'logs the transfer amount');
      return tokenInstance.allowance(accounts[0], accounts[1]);
    }).then(function(allowance) {
      assert.equal(allowance.toNumber(), 100, 'stores the allowance for delegated trasnfer');
    });
  });

  it('handles delegated token transfers', function() {
    return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      tokenInstance = instance;
      fromAccount = accounts[2];
      toAccount = accounts[3];
      spendingAccount = accounts[4];
      // Transfer some tokens to fromAccount
      return tokenInstance.transfer(fromAccount, 100, { from: accounts[0] });
    }).then(function(receipt) {
      // Approve spendingAccount to spend 10 tokens form fromAccount
      return tokenInstance.approve(spendingAccount, 10, { from: fromAccount });
    }).then(function(receipt) {
      // Try transferring something larger than the sender's balance
      return tokenInstance.transferFrom(fromAccount, toAccount, 9999, { from: spendingAccount });
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
      assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'cannot transfer value larger than balance');
      // Try transferring something larger than the approved amount
      return tokenInstance.transferFrom(fromAccount, toAccount, 20, { from: spendingAccount });
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error) {
      assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'cannot transfer value larger than approved amount');
      return tokenInstance.transferFrom.call(fromAccount, toAccount, 10, { from: spendingAccount });
    }).then(function(success) {
      assert.equal(success, true);
      return tokenInstance.transferFrom(fromAccount, toAccount, 10, { from: spendingAccount });
    }).then(function(receipt) {
      assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1, 'triggers one event');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event, 'Transfer', 'should be the "Transfer" event');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._from, fromAccount, 'logs the account the tokens are transferred from');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._to, toAccount, 'logs the account the tokens are transferred to');
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._value, 10, 'logs the transfer amount');
      return tokenInstance.balanceOf(fromAccount);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 90, 'deducts the amount from the sending account');
      return tokenInstance.balanceOf(toAccount);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 10, 'adds the amount from the receiving account');
      return tokenInstance.allowance(fromAccount, spendingAccount);
    }).then(function(allowance) {
      assert.equal(allowance.toNumber(), 0, 'deducts the amount from the allowance');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You misuse the constructor syntax, you created a function called Dapptoken but it’s not the right syntax for a constructor. See this:

```
contract Dapptoken {
   constructor(uint256 _initialSupply){
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
    totalSupply = _initialSupply;
   }
}
```